# Quadratic-trigonometric integral

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals, change-of-variable

### Problem

I need to compute the following interval
\begin{equation*}\int_{t_\text{s}}^{t_\text{e}} \cos\left(a+b\tau+c\tau^2\right)\text{ d}\tau\end{equation*}
where $t_{\text{s}},t_{\text{e}},a,b,c$ are non-negative given parameters. I have some difficulties in the case where $b$ and $c$ are both non zero. In order to fix the ideas, I will show my solutions in the simpler case where $c=0$ and $a,b>0$.

---

#### simpler case $c=0$ and $a,b>0$

The integral above reduce to
\begin{equation*}\int_{t_\text{s}}^{t_\text{e}} \cos\left(a+b\tau\right)\text{ d}\tau\end{equation*}
the idea is to integrate with respect
\begin{equation*}h(\tau)\triangleq a+b\tau\end{equation*}
so it turns out
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}\int_{h(t_\text{s})}^{h(t_\text{e})} \cos\left(h\right)\left(\frac{\text{ d}h}{b}\right)&=\frac{\sin(h)}{b}\bigg|_{h(t_{\text{s}})}^{h(t_\text{e})}\\
&=\frac{\sin(a+bt_{\text{e}})-\sin(a+bt_{\text{s}})}{b}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}

---

#### general case $a,b,c>0$

Now seems that the substitution trick does not work. Indeed, now the full integral
\begin{equation*}\int_{t_\text{s}}^{t_\text{e}} \cos\left(a+b\tau+c\tau^2\right)\text{ d}\tau\end{equation*}
requires the change of variable
\begin{equation*}h(\tau)\triangleq a+b\tau+c\tau^2\end{equation*}
which causes the following problem: the differential $\text{d}\tau$ is a function of $\tau$ itself because
\begin{equation*}
\text{d}h=(b+2c\tau)\text{d}\tau \rightarrow
\text{d}\tau=\frac{\text{d}h}{b+2c\tau}\end{equation*}
and so, due to the presence of $\tau$ in the above expressions, the substitution does not work.

---

### Question

At a first glance the general integral that I'm trying to compute does not seem so problematic: the integrand is just the composition of a cosine with a polynomial function, i.e. two very regular functions. I don't believe that there is no solution, so I'm asking if someone can give me some ideas to carry out the calculation.

Comment: You can complete the square to get an expression of the form $cos(Kx^2 + L)$. Such an expression integrated is a "Fresnel integral" https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html . You may also be interested in Gaussian integrals, to which this is strongly related.

Comment: Thank you so much, your idea works like a charm.
Actually that's the first time that I hear about the Fresnel integral. Now, due to your suggestion, I'm wondering if I can express the result in terms of the more familiar $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by @egglog, you can reduce to Fresnel integrals. WLOG, $c>0$ and you can change the variable using

$$a+b\tau+c\tau^2=\upsilon^2+\tfrac\Delta{4c}$$
where $\upsilon=\sqrt c\left(\tau+\tfrac b{2c}\right)$. This gives
$$\int_{t_s}^{t_e}\cos(a+b\tau+c\tau^2)\,d\tau=\frac1{\sqrt c}\int_{u_s}^{u_e}\left(\cos\left(\tfrac\Delta{4c}\right)\cos(\upsilon^2)-\sin\left(\tfrac\Delta{4c}\right)\sin(\upsilon^2)\right)\,d\upsilon\\
=\frac{\cos\left(\frac\Delta{4c}\right)}{\sqrt c}\left(C\left(a'+bt_e+ct_e^2\right)-C\left(a'+bt_s+ct_s^2\right)\right)
\\-\frac{\sin\left(\frac\Delta{4c}\right)}{\sqrt c}\left(S\left(a'+bt_e+ct_e^2\right)-S\left(a'+bt_s+ct_s^2\right)\right)$$

where $a':=a-\frac\Delta{4c}$.

Comment: thank you, now the answer to my question is very clear.